# How to block this recursive equation

Tags: recursion

Just trying to solve this recursive equation. I tried to use an iteration method and I'm struggling to understand how to determine when the iteration is over (first iteration: $n^{0.5}$, second $n^{0.25}$, third $n^{0.125}$).

$$T(n) = T(\sqrt{n}) + 17$$

Comment: Is that supposed to be $T(n)=T(\sqrt n)+17$ ? Is there any other information? That equation doesn't make sense for $n=0$ or $n=1$.

Comment: Yeah that's it, and i see it too that it doesn't make sense for this cases but what about other cases

Comment: What does *block* mean?

Comment: Is it $T(\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor)$?

Answer (score 0):

If the recurrence is actually $T(n) = T(\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor) + 17$, then the solution is $T(n)=T(1)+17L(n)$, where $L(n) = k$ for $n \in [2^k,2^{k+1})$.

$L(n)$ is closely related to $\log_2^*(n)$, the [iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) in base $2$.

Answer (score 0):

A solution $T : (1,+\infty) \to \mathbb R$ is:
$$
T(n) = 17 \log_{2}\log_2 n +\alpha\big(\log_{2}\log_2 n\big),
\qquad n > 1
$$
where $\alpha$ is any real function with period $1$.